# Transfer old log files before they are deleted by logrotate

Tags: debian, rsyslog, logrotate

I'm using Debian Stretch on my server. Here is the relevant portion of `etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`:

```
/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

After there are four logfiles for `mail.log`, the oldest file is deleted. This is fine, but I want to transfer the file via scp to a remote server before it's deleted.

How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `prerotate` block can do this. The simplest form would be

```
prerotate
   scp mail.log.4.gz user@remotehost:
endscript
```

Comment: If the final goal is to have all the files on the other machine, copying *.log.1.gz right after it's created will work just as well (and fewer logs will be lost is the machine goes tits up).

Comment: Thanks Chris & xenoid! I'll test this out and let you know how it goes. And you're right, xenoid, that would make more sense to export them right away.

Comment: Another question... Since my logrotate block specifies multiple files, I assume this block will execute 4 times when logrotate is run. Does that mean the prerotate block will run four times (and thus try to upload the file four times)???

Comment: @pkSML the ``sharedscripts`` directive means that the prerotate only executes once even if there are multiple files - see https://serverfault.com/questions/744062/logrotate-run-the-postrotate-after-all-processing/873002#873002 for some discussion (and logrotate man pages)

Comment: @ChrisHill Thanks for the clarification! I read that link and I'll definitely check into the man pages. When next week begins, I expect I'll see the uploaded file sent to me!